# How can I specify prefix parameters when saving a nested ActiveResource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeresource, ruby-1.9.3

I have a nested ActiveResource model (i.e. it's within another model's namespace). Trying to call `save` raises:

```
ActiveResource::MissingPrefixParam: client_id prefix_option is missing
```

How do I supply the needed prefix?

Here's my class:

```
class Foo::Bar < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://www.example.com"
  self.prefix = "/clients/:client_id"
  self.element_name = "policy"
  self.collection_name = "policies"
end
```

Here's my save attempt:

```
bar = Foo::Bar.new :client_id => 123
bar.valid? # => true
bar.client_id # => 123
bar.save # => ActiveResource::MissingPrefixParam...
```

Time and again I've looked for elucidation on this, but I only find the same instruction:

`When a GET is requested for a nested resource and you don’t provide the prefix_param an ActiveResource::MissingPrefixParam will be raised.`

I'm trying to access our server's API endpoint at `http://www.example.com/clients/[client_id]/policies`, but I'm apparently failing to supply `client_id`, so my app makes its request to `http://www.example.com/clients//policies`

The server log tells me: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/clients//policies/" with {:method=>:post})`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work if you create a method `prefix_options`, which supplies a Hash containing the needed `client_id prefix_option`, like so:

```
def prefix_options
  { :client_id => client_id }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you want to create a new policy for a particular client. The path to which you should post your policy details should be:

```
client_policies_path(@client.id)
```

If you are using a form, you can use form_for like this:

```
form_for [@client, @policy] do
```

where `@client` and `@policy` are created by the `#new` action in your PolicyController like this:

```
def new
  @client = Client.new(params[:client_id])
  @policy = @client.policies.build
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. (I can't see how it would work, but I tried it all anyway). 1) There's no `client_policies_path` (I'm using `ActiveResource`, not `ActiveRecord`, so the route doesn't exist in my routes file; it's specified in the Model). 2) I'm not using a form (I'm using console), and setting controller attributes `@policy` and `@client` have no bearing on the outcome. I'm using `ActiveResource` and merely calling `save` on the instance. The policy instance in question already knows its own `:client_id`.  -- Am I misunderstanding your answer?